# Does running this addEventListener in a loop with anonymous functions create 30 seperate function objects?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, anonymous-function, nodelist

Question 1a:
Hi I am wondering if running version 1 of the following code would result 
in the creation of multiple anonymous functions (at the addEventListener part), one for each element of the clickable node list?

Question 1b:
In version 2 I simply passed addEventListener a reference to another function. Is there a benefit to version 2 versus version 1?

Both my question are related. I am not sure whether addEventListener shares anonymous functions between different elements. Please be as detailed as you'd like. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance. :)

Extra information: I am expecting the length of the clickable node list to be between 28 and 31 (calendar).

Version 1:

```
Base.prototype.addCalendarClickEffect = function () {
    let clickable_node_list = this.clickable_node_list
    let lastElementClicked = null;

        for(let i = 0; i< clickable_node_list.length; i++){
          clickable_node_list[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
              if(lastElementClicked){
                lastElementClicked.classList.remove("clicked");
              }
              event.target.classList.add("clicked");
              lastElementClicked = event.target;
          });
        }
}
```

Version 2:

```
Base.prototype.addCalendarClickEffect = function () {
    let clickable_node_list = this.clickable_node_list

        for(let i = 0; i< clickable_node_list.length; i++){
          clickable_node_list[i].addEventListener("click", toggleClickedClass);
        }
}

function toggleClickedClass(event) {
  if(lastElementClicked){
    lastElementClicked.classList.remove("clicked");
  }
  event.target.classList.add("clicked");
  lastElementClicked = event.target;
}
```

Comment: BTW in version 2 lastElementClicked is declared in the surrounding IFFE.

Comment: Every time a `function() {...}` expression is encountered, it evaluates as a new function, just like every time `{...}` object literal is encountered, it creates a different object: `{a: 1} != {a: 1}`, and `(function() { return 1 }) != (function() { return 1 })`. Yes, Version 2 is better, though not a big deal with 30 elements.

Comment: If you don't want to add many separate listeners, use event delegation instead.

Comment: You can put one event handler on the parent node of the node_list and have it handle all child events.

Comment: Thank you I have updated the code to use event delegation instead. It is available here for all interested. :) https://github.com/Pirsanth/Journal/blob/master/assets/base.js